# How to detect contrast index of a photo?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm trying to take a group of photos (with the addition that *more photos* can be added *after*), and try to find a contrast/brightness/saturation index that I can use to sort the photos. Brightness and saturation is pretty easy, but I'm stuck with finding the contrast. I've tried several things (average of difference of all pixels with their neighbors, or splitting into 16 zones (4x4) and averaging difference of their averages, to fight against noise's added contrast in the previous method) but nothing gives me accurate results. My meaning of the *contrast* term is nothing technical/scientific, just visually high or low contrast, the one that you look by your eye and say. I am no expert of math or signal processing, and I'm looking for a simple and straightforward algorithm, if any. How do I get an overall numeric contrast index/ratio/value/whatever (as long as it can be used to sort photos) of an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to make a histogram of pixel brightness. For "ideal" contrast image it should be uniform. And deviation from the uniformity could be quantity of contrast.

For more details, see histogram equalization method of contrast enhancing:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this, but I'd try the following steps one after another:

1. Noise removal. Any sort of it. Depending on how much computation you can do, I'll try either blurring (cheap), median, or a [Bilateral Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilateral_filter) (more expensive, and possibly requires knowing the noise is more or less of the same type/effect/contrast in all the images). Note that all filters require you to know a radius which is enough to remove the noise, yet won't harm local contrast (I do hope that you have more of a global contrast than local contrast)
2. Create some histogram of the image brightness. Either on all the pixels, or divide it into parts (like the 16 parts you suggested above) if you want to work on a fixed size histogram.
3. Compute the [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the image histogram. That will be the parameter for image contrast.

Comment: for the first part, I decided to work with thumbnails (which I already generate) of the images, to dramatically reduce processing and also get rid of noise factors...